# CouchDB cluster authentication

Tags: couchdb

I was able to setup a Couchdb cluster of 3 nodes, and did load-balancing between the three nodes using HAProxy. I added a couple of databases, couple of documents, and everything worked as expected.

My problem was with authentication, I’m using authentication through cookies, the problem is that the cookie seems to be valid only in the node that issued the cookie, the other two nodes, tells me that I don’t have the required authorization.

I am aware of the “sticky-session” configuration in HAProxy, but I don’t want to use it, because of my application needs, a single client load must be balanced through all the three couchdb nodes, and thus must use the cookie for all the 3 nodes.

I’m also aware that using basic-auth would solve my issue, but I don’t want to retain passwords in the client.

So, is there a way to make a cookie issued by node A to be valid in node B and node C? Given that all 3 nodes have the same users, and the same admin credentials (same username, password).

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem right now and the answer below (although it is what the docs state) does not work for me. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: What went wrong for me in this case was the following: I set the admin user in my test setup using `COUCHDB_USER` and `COUCHDB_PASS` environment variables. This would create a new salt for each node which makes the session valid for a single node only. Instead, I specified my admin user in the ini file and got the loadbalanced cluster working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they must all have the same [couch_httpd_auth secret setting](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.3.1/config/auth.html#couch_httpd_auth/secret) in their configuration to respect cookies issued by each other. If you do not set the secret then it is randomly generated separately by each node causing them to reject cookies from the other nodes.